# pass props in nested stackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm a beinner in React-Native and i'm using `stackNavigator` from `react-navigation` package to create a Wizard. But i can't pass parameters between different screens of stacks:

```
class TaskWizard extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      let {service} = this.getNavigationParams()
      this.state = {
         model : {service.fields}
      }
   }

   getNavigationParams() {
      return this.props.navigation.state.params || {}
   }
}


const TaskWizardStack = createStackNavigator({
    Wizard : {
      screen : TaskWizard,
    },
})


const PostTaskStack = createStackNavigator({
     // some screens here then Task wizard
     Deep : {
       screen : Deep
     }
     TaskWizard : {
       screen : TaskWizardStack
     }
})
export default PostTaskStack
```

I know i can pass parameters to a screen like this from `Deep` component :

```
<View>
   <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('TaskWizard', {
                         service: {id : 1, fields : [{}]} },
                      })
    />
</View>
```

This will pass `service` parameter from inside of `Deep` component   to `TaskWizard` Stack. I need to pass it from TaskWizard to every child screens like `Wizard`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using screenprops to pass the data to other components

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props

Answer (score -1):

Code below works for me

```
    export const AdminBottomNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {Home: {screen: SchoolDashboard},
    Students: {screen: StudentList},
    Message: {screen: Dashboard},
    Settings: {screen: StudentList},}, 
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => 
    ({tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => 
    {let screenProps=navigation.getScreenProps();}})})
```